# IBM PCOMM with Java

Tags: java, hacl

I'm totally new to this PCOMM things so I have a question. I'm using the "Personal Communications" Software by IBM. I also have an Visual Basic PCOMM sript which I want to rewrite in java.

Is there some kind of documentation of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When I google with the query **PCOMM Documentation** I've got the Personal Communications for Windows, Version 5.6 - Quick Beginnings and when use Goolge Books I can come around 2 articles on **InfoWorld**.

Why not you can try for? I think it would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I found some Links in my research to it...
I mostly struggled with having no javadoc in the past and explored the library to see what works but in the below links there is the javadoc for it ;-)

I've written a library to easily do testautomation on the mainframe but it's company specific and closed source, anyway you can get back to me if you have a question and I see if I can answer i.

Just one note on multithreading:
Basically it is possible but the native library gets loaded once and used for all threads and this lib is not thread safe.
If you do multithreading, you have totake care that you don't try to interact with two mainframe sessions at the same time.
I just implemented an managing wueue where the threads request for a slot and then go to wait state and the managing thread just loops over the queue, wakes the specific thread and waits until he gives the slot back (just make sure you can't get into a deadlock).

Due to stackoverflow hyperlinks restriction, find all link here: http://nopaste.info/ed31e94351.html

The most important one (at least for me) is the javadoc inside the hacl.zip file on the ftp:
ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/webserver/hostondemand/library/

Answer (score 0):

According to IBM's Personal Communications Host Access Class Library book:

> The documentation for the HACL Java classes is provided in HTML
>   format. These files are available in the ..\doc\hacl subdirectory of
>   the Personal Communications installation image. To view the
>   documentation, use a Web browser to view the ECLReference.html file,
>   which is the first file of the softcopy HACL Java reference.